# Build only and not Deploy

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server

Quick question. I was wondering is there any way to just build an app made in WL6, without the need to deploy to the server?

I know that in Cordova you can simply just run: `cordova build android` in terminal, but I can't seem to find an option on the WL IDE to do this...

I'm just wanting to test the UI standalone without server functionality. Rather than waiting for a deployment each time (I know it doesn't take too long but just looking to save a little time).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using Worklight Studio 6.0.0.x (the Eclipse plug-in).
You could possibly use [an Ant task to build the application/adapter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/r_ant_tasks_buld_deploy_apps.html).

Answer (score 0):

The deployment to the internal development server is pretty fast and gives you the capability of testing your UI through a web browser or the mobile web simulator. I typically will use the browser with the Ripple Emulator plugin in Chrome to get the sizing right without waiting on the Java simulator to start.

The slowest component in my environment is waiting for the Android emulator to run, so I try to avoid that.

Here's a tip if you are testing the UI on-device or are using a component such as JSONStore, which requires an full device or emulator to run:

1. Set up your application to check for updates from the Worklight server.
2. Point the application at the embedded development server (this is the default for dev)
3. Keep your device connected when you do Build and Deploy in Worklight Studio.
4. Restart the app on the device and it will load the new version.

As long as you aren't changing native code such as Cordova plugins, this lets you iterate UI changes and test them on the real device without the time to do a new app deployment or waiting on the compilers and emulators.

Comment: you can make your android emulator much faster. check out this video, it is for mac, but same can be done for Windows as well. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjmTlDgckw0

Comment: *"are using a component such as JSONStore, which requires an full device or emulator to run"* **FYI:** JSONStore works fine without a device or emulator (JavaScript-only environment) if you're using Worklight >= 6.0.